# Concept behind using callable variable

Tags: php

I have been given a API which I am currently back engineering. there is one function in particular that gives me troubles with fully understanding its purpose/use.

```
private function split($data, Callable $callback)
{
    $split = array();
    if ($data) {
        $split = array_map(function($joined) use ($callback) {
            return $callback(explode('::', $joined));
        }, explode(',', $data));
    }

    return $split;
}
```

I dont fully understand the concept of `Callable`, and function within `array_map`, `function($joined)` then this function USE callable variable, Could someone explain this concept form me please

Comment: Its give you the possibility to hook your own function in the existing code without changing the source code of the API. This technique is called code plumbing

Comment: Sorry if am being lame here...but when you say 'possibility to hook your own function' do you mean like the given data for Callable will be treated as a seperate function every time...?

Answer (score 2):

A Callable argument is an argument that you can call ! As you can see in the code, the argument `$callback` is used like a function: `$callback(...)`

This is called high-order programming and this is really useful in certain cases. A simple example: Let's say you have to code a function that adds 2 and another function that multiplies by 2 every elements of an array. A simple but verbose way to do that is:

```
function multiply($array) {
    $results = array();
    foreach ($array as $number) {
        $results[] = $number * 2;
    }
    return $results;
}

function add($array) {
    $results = array();
    foreach ($array as $number) {
        $results[] = $number + 2;
    }
    return $results;
}
```

A lot of code is the same in the 2 functions. High-order programming is useful in this case, what you can do is create a function `apply($function, $array)` that apply the function `$function` to all the elements of $array and returns an array with the result.

```
function apply($function, $array) {
    $results = array();
    foreach ($array as $number) {
        $results[] = $function($number);
    }
    return $results;
}
```

Now, if you want to multiply all the elements by 2 or add 2, you simply do:

```
function multiply($array) {
    return apply(function($number) {
        return $number * 2;
    }, $array);
}

function add($array) {
    return apply(function($number) {
        return $number + 2;
    }, $array);
}
```

You see, we give a function as an argument to the `apply` function. This function (called `$function` in `apply`) is applied to all the elements of `$array`, and `apply` returns the results (called `$results`).

The PHP function `array_map` does exactly the same thing. When your code calls `array_map`, it gives a function that takes one argument (the element of the array to process) and returns the processed element (here, it simply applies the function `$callback` to it).